# ??? Undefined function or variable

Tags: matlab, function, error-handling

Why do i get the error

> ??? Undefined function or variable

when trying to call the following function:

```
    function Diff= myfun3(wk,omega)
wcalc=inv(lambda* Passetcovar)*inv(inv(tau * Passetcovar)+ PMat(i,:)'*inv(omega)*PMat(i,:))*(inv(tau * Passetcovar)*Pi+ PMat(i,:)'*inv(omega)*Q(i,:));
Diff=sum((wk-wcalc).^2);
end
```

All the parameters in the function are defined and correct.

I am calling this function using `myfun3(wk,omega)` but I get error messages such as

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'lambda'.
```

Even when lambda has been defined eslewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` isn't defined in the function workspace, even if it is defined in your base workspace. Either pass it as an input to the function or define it as a global variable. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html for more details.

Comment: Correct, you haven't defined `i` either. It depends what you are trying to do. Are you looping over `i`? What does your function do? How do you expect to run it? With which data?

Comment: Yes, i noticed that I hadn't included i in the function call and it works fine now- thank you! The whole point is to get this function working so that I can minimise it by varying omega- something I still haven't managed to do (see my other question). Thanks again!